# Callable with different return types

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, callable

I would like to execute different methods in a separate thread depending on the parameters that are given to the constructor. However, the Callable interface only allows one kind of return parameter.

It should work like this:

```
Future<String> result =
       executor.submit(ClassThatImplementsCallable(RETURN_STRING));
Future<Integer> result =
       executor.submit(ClassThatImplementsCallable(RETURN_INT));

ClassThatImplementsCallable(RETURN_NOTHING);
```

To return either null (respectively the reference to Void) or any other type like String or Integer I have to use T without any bounds like this:

```
public static class CallableTest<T> implements Callable<T>{
    T value;
    CallableTest(T value) {
       this.value = value;
    }
    public T call(){    
       return value;   
    }    
}
```

However, this is not what I want to achieve, but it also doesn't make sense to extend Void and implement some other interface.

Comment: If they are not returning the same thing they should probably be different methods. You can always return the ignore values of a method just so you are aware.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I would like to execute different methods in a separate thread depending on the parameters that are given to the constructor.

So when you submit a `Callable` to an `ExecutorService`, you get a future with the same type:

```
Future<String> stringResult = executor.submit(new MyCallable<String>());
Future<Integer> stringResult = executor.submit(new MyCallable<Integer>());
```

What you *can't* do is have a single `Future result` that returns one of two different types, either `String` or `Integer`, based on arguments when the `ExecutorService` was constructed.  I think that is what you are asking.

One alternative would be for you to create a little wrapper class:

```
public class StringOrInteger {
    final String s;
    final Integer i;
    public StringOrInteger(String s) {
        this.s = s;
        this.i = null;
    }
    public StringOrInteger(Integer i) {
        this.s = null;
        this.i = i;
    }
    public boolean isString() {
        return this.s != null;
    }
}
```

Then your executor will submit `Callable<StringOrInteger>` and the instances of `StringOrInteger` returned by the `Future<StringOrInteger>` will either the `s` or `i` field will be set.

An extremely ugly alternative would be to return `Object` and use `instanceof` to figure out what type it is.  But I won't even show the code for that implementation because it would give me hives.

Comment: Thank you. I hope I have understood that correctly: Generics with bounded type parameters can't be a solution in this context, because only things like ClassThatImplementsCallable<T extends Number & CharSequence> implements Callable<T> are allowed? How could I make the Callable's call method return void or some other typ?

Comment: What?  A given `Executor` can handle `Callable`s with any return type.  You just have to pass it a `Callable<T>` of the appropriate `T`.  It'd be fine to have `executor.submit(new ClassThatImplementsCallable<String>(RETURN_STRING));  executor.submit(new ClassThatImplementsCallable<Integer>(RETURN_INT));`

Comment: Yeah I need to fix some of my answer @LouisWasserman.  Thanks.  I've never even thought about submitting `Callable`s that return different types to an `ExecutorService` but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks. Could I also return Void or a String arbitrarily like `class CallableClass<T extends Void & CharSequence> implements Callable<T>`?

Comment: No @user181237.  That won't compile.

Comment: So `Callable<Void>` does only make sense if you want to say "this method doesn't return anything", because the option to return null is implicitly contained in any other declaration for T like
`<T extends Number>`. I had a misconception of the Void-object in my mind, thinking it was something different than a reference to null. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Passing `Callable<T>` to executor works, but what if I'm using a `CompletionService` to collect the results? The following only works for `Future<String>` ...  `CompletionService<String> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executor)`, so how to make it work for different `Future<T>`?

Comment: @raffian: it's not doable with `CompletionService`.  A `CompletionService` is tied to one specific type.  (You could have multiple `CompletionService`s tied to the same `Executor`, though.)

Comment: I address this in my answer @raffian.  You can do the `Object` hack or you can return a wrapper class.

Comment: @Gray, I like the `instanceof` approach; after identifying the type, a simple cast gives me the object (and methods) I need. The wrapper approach is sort of the same in terms of work; need to check all attributes for the non-null values, so either way I'm checking something, whether value or type. You were kidding about the hives? :-D

Answer (score 1):

you could use the Command pattern together with Visitor pattern.

Define a command class and wrap your processing logic together with parameters and return types in it. then pass this command object as parameter and also use it as result type.

Later in your code you can use visitor pattern in order to deal with the two concrete commands.